# Ubuntu killed all settings, messed windows 7

Tags: windows, settings

After installing ubuntu to empty partition, without Wubi,
all my win7 PROGRAMS settings were wiped, for example -
bittorrent loads default settings (iv spend a lot of time customizing it)
firefox opens with default settings EVERY TIME, not saving any settings anymore.

So how do I resolve this?

Comment: Unless you formatted your Windows partition, installing Ubuntu would not affect any settings within Windows. Perhaps it was a coincidence that you experienced your Windows problems around the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not ever touch your Windows stuff unless you explicitly say that you want it to. And during install, you'll either loose Windows by overwriting its filesystem, or it will not be affected.